# oracle - assign a sequence to a partition by group

Tags: oracle, partition

```
select row_number() over(partition by col1,col2), col1, col2, col3 
from table1 
where xxxx...
```

when using the query above, how do I assign a sequence.nextval to each group ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to solve this using just SQL. The problem is that any reference to a sequence in SQL will be evaluated separately for each row.

Using PL/SQL, you can loop through the results of your query and update each partition:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cur_partitions IS
      SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
      FROM   table1
      WHERE  some_column = some_condition;

   v_seq NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR r_partition IN cur_partition LOOP
      v_seq := your_sequence.NEXTVAL;

      UPDATE table1
      SET    seq_column = v_seq
      WHERE      col1 = r_partition.col1
             AND col2 = r_partition.col2
             AND some_column = some_condition;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: In 19C the merge statement is giving me `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`. Would you please verify?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen: I rolled back to the previous version that did not contain the `merge`.