# Oracle Generate a unique sequence value for each group of rows, partitioned by some column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

```
drop table foo;

create table foo (c1 varchar2(10), c2 int);

insert into foo values ('A', 10);
insert into foo values ('A', 11);
insert into foo values ('B', 12);
insert into foo values ('B', 13);

create sequence foo_s;
```

I would like to group these rows by C1 (A or B), and generate a single sequence value for every row in the same group. For example, the two rows with C1=A should have the same sequence generated number (for example 1024), while the two rows with C1=B would have the same sequence generated number (for example 1025):

I want to do something like the following which of course is invalid syntax:

```
select c1, c2, foo_s.nextval over (partition by c1) batch_id
from foo
```

Which outputs the following:

```
c1  |  c2  | batch_id
A   |  10  |  1024
A   |  11  |  1024
B   |  12  |  1025
B   |  13  |  1025
```

I want to do this in a pure SQL Select statement. Failing that I suppose a merge/update is OK. As a last resort I could do it in PL/SQL.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350189/oracle-assign-a-sequence-to-a-partition-by-group) uses a MERGE instead of SELECT, and is failing for me with ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

---

In PostgreSQL, it is possible to use a Sequence this way. For example:

```
select c1, c2, first_value(batch_id) over (partition by c1) 
from (
    select c1, c2, nextval('foo_s') batch_id from foo
) foo;
```

There are several other alternative ways. But it seems like using the sequence in Oracle will always result in ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

You commented that the final result will reside in another table; you didn't post it so I'll assume several things - see if it helps.

This is a source table (you posted):

```
SQL> select * From foo;

C1                 C2
---------- ----------
A                  10
A                  11
B                  12
B                  13
```

This is a target table:

```
SQL> create table test (c1 varchar2(5), c2 number, batch_id number);

Table created.
```

Query doesn't require any sequence (as Oracle object); everything is done from existing data. A CTE finds the last `batch_id` and then adds value generated by the `dense_rank` analytic function:

```
SQL> insert into test (c1, c2, batch_id)
  2  with max_bid as
  3    (select nvl(max(batch_id), 0) max_bid from test)
  4  select f.c1,
  5    f.c2,
  6    dense_rank() over (order by f.c1) + m.max_bid as batch_id
  7  from foo f cross join max_bid m;

4 rows created.
```

Contents of the target table:

```
SQL> select * from test;

C1            C2   BATCH_ID
----- ---------- ----------
A             10          1
A             11          1
B             12          2
B             13          2

SQL>
```

Now, as you didn't explain how exactly will you generate next data set, I'll just truncate source table and insert some more rows into it. You'll, perhaps, have some date column (so you'll always take "today's data"), or ... who know, but you?

```
SQL> truncate table foo;

Table truncated.

SQL> insert all
  2    into foo values ('A', 20)
  3    into foo values ('A', 21)
  4    into foo values ('B', 22)
  5    into foo values ('B', 23)
  6  select * From dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> select * From foo;

C1                 C2
---------- ----------
A                  20
A                  21
B                  22
B                  23

SQL>
```

Re-run the same `INSERT` statement:

```
SQL> insert into test (c1, c2, batch_id)
  2  with max_bid as
  3    (select nvl(max(batch_id), 0) max_bid from test)
  4  select f.c1,
  5    f.c2,
  6    dense_rank() over (order by f.c1) + m.max_bid as batch_id
  7  from foo f cross join max_bid m;

4 rows created.
```

which results in

```
SQL> select * from test;

C1            C2   BATCH_ID
----- ---------- ----------
A             10          1
A             11          1
B             12          2
B             13          2
A             20          3
A             21          3
B             22          4
B             23          4

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

`batch_id` is incremented, as you wanted.

Comment: This works and I think I will use it, thanks. But is there no way to do it with a sequence generated value? For example this can be done in postgresql this way: `select c1, c2, first_value(batch_id) over (partition by c1) from (select c1, c2, nextval('foo_s') batch_id from foo) foo` In Oracle the equivalent fails with `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`. The nice thing about the sequence is that it is atomic, whereas using this MAX(batch_id) is not. In my case I'm just using a single thread and can ensure a single thread, so this point doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat assignment each query:

```
SELECT c1, c2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c1) batch_id
  FROM foot
```

Assign new batch1 values only when there are new C1 values:

```
MERGE INTO foo2 tgt
USING (WITH data AS (SELECT src.c1,
                             src.c2,
                             tgt.batch_id
                        FROM foo src,
                             (SELECT c1,MAX(batch_id) batch_id
                                FROM foo2
                               GROUP BY c1) tgt
                       WHERE src.c1 = tgt.c1(+))     
        SELECT *  -- remove this SELECT if you don't need to re-update existing rows for some other reason. they already have the correct batch_id
          FROM data
         WHERE batch_id IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT c1,
               c2,
               x.last_batch_id + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c1) batch_id
          FROM data,
               (SELECT MAX(batch_id) last_batch_id
                  FROM data) x
         WHERE batch_id IS NULL) src
    ON (src.c1 = tgt.c1,
        src.c2 = tgt.c2)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.batch_id = src.batch_id
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (c1,c2,batch_id)
                       VALUES (src.c1,src.c2,src.batch_id)
```

Comment: I want to use a sequence generated value from `foo_s.nextval`. The value generated needs to be unique over time. Using row_number or dense_rank results in duplicate values when the query is run a second time.

Comment: You won't be able to escape writing your sequence numbers to a table somewhere. Otherwise how could previous assignments be remembered and honored rather than generating new numbers?

Comment: Yes I plan on writing the results of this query to a table. But sequence generated values always generate new numbers each time you call them. You don't need to save them to a table. Using row_number/dense_rank will always start from 1, resulting in duplicates over time. You can check the PL/SQL solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350189/oracle-assign-a-sequence-to-a-partition-by-group) which makes clear what I am going for.

Comment: That PL/SQL solution would generate new numbers every time you run the query.  If the table had 100 groups of C1 and you executed that PL/SQL 100 times with the same data, you will have advanced the sequence by 10,000, even though its the same set of data every time. Is that what you want? Or do you want to generate new numbers only when there is a new C1 value you haven't seen before? That'd follow different logic.

Comment: Edited my answer with another option. Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table foo;
create table foo (c1 varchar2(10), c2 int);

insert into foo values ('A', 10);
insert into foo values ('A', 11);
insert into foo values ('B', 12);
insert into foo values ('B', 13);

drop sequence foo_s;
create sequence foo_s;

DROP TABLE temp_tbl;

CREATE TABLE temp_tbl AS
SELECT
            d.distinct_c1,
            foo_s.nextval as val
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT c1 AS distinct_c1
            FROM
                foo
        
        )d;

SELECT
    foo.c1,
    foo.c2,
    t.val
 FROM
    foo
 LEFT JOIN
    temp_tbl t
ON
    t.distinct_c1=foo.c1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may isolate `sequence.nextval` into a function and use the function in any place. Since 12c it is possible to declare functions within `select` statement.

> ```
> create view test_batch
> as
> with function f_get_seq
> return number
> as
>   pragma udf;
> begin
>   return foo_s.nextval;
> end;
>
> grp as (
>   select
>     c1, f_get_seq() as batch_id
>   from foo
>   group by c1
> )
> select *
> from foo
>   join grp
>   using(c1)
> ```

```
select *
from test_batch
```

| C1 | C2 | BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 12 | 2 |
| B | 13 | 2 |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| A | 11 | 1 |

```
select *
from test_batch
```

| C1 | C2 | BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 3 |
| A | 11 | 3 |
| B | 12 | 4 |
| B | 13 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wyGfIDd4?hide=56)

**UPD**.

Or, if you want to avoid double access to the `foo`, the same with `match_recognize`:

> ```
> create view test_batch
> as
> with function f_get_seq
> return number
> as
>   pragma udf;
> begin
>   return foo_s.nextval;
> end;
>
> select *
> from foo
> match_recognize (
>   partition by c1
>   measures
>     final first(f_get_seq()) as batch_id
>   all rows per match
>   pattern (a+)
>   define
>     a as 1=1
> )
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x1RqPAig?hide=56)

... or with `model`:

> ```
> create view test_batch
> as
> with function f_get_seq
> return number
> as
>   pragma udf;
> begin
>   return foo_s.nextval;
> end;
>
> select *
> from foo
> model
>   partition by (c1)
>   dimension by (
>     row_number() over(partition by c1 order by null) as rn
>   )
>   measures (
>     c2, 0 as batch_id
>   )
>   rules update (
>     batch_id[1] = f_get_seq(),
>     batch_id[rn > 1] = batch_id[1]
>   )
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H9wPk0na?hide=56)